# Is there a way to simplify this expression including summation, powers of 2 and binomial coefficients

Tags: number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients, exponentiation

I have an expression as:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}{(-1)^k}\binom{m}{k}{(2)^{n(m-k)}}$$

Constraints:
$1\le n, m \le 10^{6}$

It is a programming question and I am required to find the answer $\pmod {10^{9} + 7}$. I can do it in O(m) time complexity using preprocessing. I didn't post this on stack overflow because it involves more math and little programming. I have to calculate the above expression for different pairs $(m, n)$ , so is there a way to find it faster or some closed form.

Comment: this is binomial theorem. Where is this problem from?

Comment: @Phicar This would have been binomial theorem if there was no n in the power of 2

Comment: @abiessu No, as you can see, they are different. The main problem I am having solving this is the term n in power of 2.

Comment: @risingStark No. $n$ is constant in the sum. Is this an ongoing contest?

Comment: @Phicar I agree that n is a constant but how can I convert it into a closed expression. No, this is not an ongoing contest

Comment: @ZAhmed Can you provide some explanation or proof for the same?

Comment: $2^{ab} = (2^a)^b$

Comment: @risingStark you may that your sum is $(2^n-1)^m$ in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binomial Theorem: $$(1-x)^{m}=\sum_{k=0}^{m} {m \choose k} (-x)^k~~~~~(1)$$
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{m}{(-1)^k}\binom{m}{k}{(2)^{n(m-k)}}=2^{nm} \sum_{k=0}^{m} {m \choose k}(-2^{-n})^k=2^{nm}(1-\frac{1}{2^n})^m=(2^n-1)^m.$$